# Address space map R/W

Tags: assembly, memory-management, computer-science, cpu-architecture, low-level

What results are returned when Reading / Writing to space, where no memory is mapped? What is inside this "Nothing" areas?

**EDIT 1**

In context of x86

[image]

Comment: You forgot to specify what architecture. In general, when reading, you either get a fault, some random value or zero. Writing is again either a fault or the value is just discarded.

Comment: Depends on the architecture. On a lot of systems it is basically undefined behavior. Often hardware beyond the CPU deals with it. It could silently throw away writes, and reads could return a default value (like 0xff or 0x00). External hardware (from the CPU itself) could potentially drive a hardware interrupt to the processor to trap the read/write error. It really depends on the processor, and the design of the system as to what would happen.

Comment: wow then mmu got a lot work to do ,memory fault, if there there is no mmu in system then god know what it would result in.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realized it can have more reactions. Question has been edited.

Comment: the answer is still the same "it depends".  you would have to get extremely specific which means that greatly narrows the audience of folks with the same system.  in general dont assume there is a single answer for a question like this.  it could hang, it could be mapped by the mmu to something else, it could wrap around for some boundary, it could float high or be tied low.  (often float high or wrap around is the answer).

Comment: The most important question here is: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: That would be a valid stackoverflow question "When I tried reading this address space (See picture) I got X and dont understand why."

Comment: Ok dwelch, thank you. So you're suggesting to delete my post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the sequence the processor goes through if you access a memory location (page) is:

1. Is there are page table entry for the address? If not, access violation (i.e. nothing in your example).
2. Is there the page table entry marked as having a mapping? If no, access violation (a nothing area).
3. Is the currently page mapped to a physical page frame? If no, PAGE FAULT.
4. Does the process have access to the page in its current mode? If no, access violation (Not a "nothing area")

The nothings then either have no corresponding page table entry or the page table entry has no mapping.